# Does not work ios safari gradient text from background css

Tags: html, css, ios, safari

Can you please tell me how to make it work on ios safari?
This code works on google chrome.

```css
body {
  height: 200vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

div {
  font-size: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 600;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, blue 20%, red 70%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

span {
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div><span>APPLE</span></div>
```